# How to find TextEdit on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, textedit

My Java app will detect file extension and open it in Windows using wordpad, like this :

```
  public static Process Display_File(String File_Path)
  {
    String Command,Program,Suffix=File_Path.toLowerCase();
    Process process=null;

    if (Suffix.endsWith("txt") || Suffix.endsWith("json")) Program="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\word_pad.exe ";

    Command=Program+"\""+File_Path+"\"";

    try { process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return process;
  }
```

But it won't work on Mac, I know there is TextEdit.app on Mac, so how to change the above code to run it on Mac ?

After the change, it looks like this :

```
  public static Process Display_File_On_Mac(String File_Path)
  {
    String Command,Program,Suffix=File_Path.toLowerCase();
    Process process=null;

    if (Suffix.endsWith("txt") || Suffix.endsWith("json")) Program="/Applications/TextEdit.app ";

    Command=Program+"\""+File_Path+"\"";

    try { process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return process;
  }
```

But I got this error :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/TextEdit.app": error=13, Permission denied
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Keep in mind that "\" is a Windows specific separator, while as Macs use "/". Try changing that and see if it works. EDIT: And also make sure you Program is set to the correct path on a Mac, which will not match that on  Windows as first thing first, I do not think Macs have a folder called Program FIles

Comment: try to give execute permissions on TextEdit app to the user from which you are running java program

Comment: If you want to open a text file, create a process: `open PATHTOFILE` and it will open.

Comment: Also, Java convention is to use CamelCase and never capitalise variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On El-capitan, giving the below path worked for me:
`Program="open /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit";`

You can Navigate into the `TextEdit.app` folder from a terminal window and make sure you have the executable in the right place before trying it out.

Also, you need to change the setting of command like this:
`Command = Program+ " "+File_Path;`

Comment: I tried it, seems to work half way, the TextEdit app jumped up and down showed a message, saying the file couldn't be opened, because it doesn't exist, but I just checked, the file exists in the dir it's looking at, why ? How to fix ?

Comment: you need to change the setting of command like this: `Command = Program+ " "+File_Path;`. That is, the invocation should be the program name followed by a space and then the fullPath.

Comment: Now the command looks like this : /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /Users/fni/Documents/workspace/URL_Size/Result.txt   but it opens an error dialog saying I don't have permission, but the file is set to rwx for everyone including me, why ?

Comment: Yeah, I faced this too. I had to add an "open" before the actual path to the Program. See my update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, almost 99% there, it opened a terminal window, the perfect answer would be : "open myfile.txt".

Comment: yeah, just open works. I wonder if it uses the default as TextEdit in all cases or if it depends on one's setup

Answer (score 3):

Starting macOS Catalina system applications moved to /System/Applicatyions folder: https://support.apple.com/HT210650

So, new path to TextEdit is `/System/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`